# Javascript - change countDown timer to countUp time

Tags: javascript, counter

I have and html that counted down the days to my event and now the event is over, the counter is showing the days after as a negative number. How do i make the existing JS code to count up. I am fairly new to learning html and js and your knowledge is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code from the external link JS file:

```js
/*-----Countdown timer created by webnesters.com-------*/
jQuery.fn.CountingDown = function(options) {
 var settings = jQuery.extend({
  'date': null
 },
 options );
 myp=jQuery(this);
 function calculate_time(){
  var future = Date.parse(settings[
   'date'
  ]);
    var now = new Date();
 
    var difference = Math.floor((future - now) / 1000);
    var seconds = chkinteger(difference % 60);
 
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    var minutes = chkinteger(difference % 60);
 
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    var hours = chkinteger(difference % 24);
 
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 24);
    var days = difference;

 if(days.toString().length==1){
  days='0'+days;
 }
    myp.find("#seconds").text(seconds);
    myp.find("#minutes").text(minutes);
    myp.find("#hours").text(hours);
    myp.find("#days").text(days);
 }
 
 function chkinteger(integer)
 {
  if (integer < 0)
        integer = 0;
    if (integer < 10)
        return "0" + integer;
    return "" + integer;
 }
 calculate_time();
 interval = setInterval(calculate_time,1000);
};
```

Here is the code from the HTML:

```html
<h4>12 november 2016</h4>

            <div class="countdown-container" id="countdown">
                <div class="countdown-box-wrap-year">
                    <div class="countdown-box">
                        <div class="countdown-box-border-year">
                        </div>
                                            <div class="countdown-box-border-year2">
                        </div>

                        <span id="days">00</span>
                    </div>
                    <strong>Days</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="countdown-box-wrap">
                    <div class="countdown-box">
                        <div class="countdown-box-border">
                        </div>
                        <span id="hours">00</span>
                    </div>
                    <strong>Hours</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="countdown-box-wrap">
                    <div class="countdown-box">
                        <div class="countdown-box-border">
                        </div>
                        <span id="minutes">00</span>
                    </div>
                    <strong>Minutes</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="countdown-box-wrap">
                    <div class="countdown-box">
                        <div class="countdown-box-border">
                        </div>
                        <span id="seconds">00</span>
                    </div>
                    <strong>Seconds</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
             <script type="text/javascript">
             jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("#countdown").CountingDown({
                    date: "12 november 2016 14:00:00"  // Enter your countdown date and time
                });
            });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var difference = Math.floor((future - now) / 1000);
```

Becomes:

```
var difference = Math.floor((now - future) / 1000);
```

What's happening? We *were* taking the time until the future date (future minus now = time left).

We now want the time *since* that date (now minus future *[incidentally is now in the past]* = time elapsed).

Comment: I will give that try and get back with you. And that makes sense, basic math lol. Silly me.